# Django UnboundLocalError

Tags: django, django-views, django-errors

I have a simple formset used for register a donator to my database.

If I land on the page an existent entry from DB and remove a value from an form input and submit I get a UnboundLocalError.

```
Django Version: 1.3 
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError 
Exception Value: local variable 'dac' referenced before assignment
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def dizimista(request, nr_dizimista):
    dizimista = get_object_or_404(CadastroDizimista, pk=nr_dizimista, usuario=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('action') == 'Cancelar':
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/lista/")
    elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('action') == 'Salvar':
        form = FormCadastroDizimista(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=dizimista)
        if form.is_valid():
            cadastro = form.save(commit=False)
            cadastro.usuario = request.user
            cadastro.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/lista/")
    else:
        form = FormCadastroDizimista(instance=dizimista)
        dac = CadastroDizimista.objects.get(pk=nr_dizimista).datacadastro
        dam = CadastroDizimista.objects.get(pk=nr_dizimista).datamodificado
    return render_to_response("cadastro.html", {'dac': dac, 'dam': dam, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Sorry. I stressed one more time on code and discover my fault. the "dac" must be a global var. I declared it and "dam" as global inside def and voilá!

Comment: That's incorrect, in almost all cases you should not use global variables. You should populate that variables inside the view for any possible case in IF`s (maybe populate them before first IF). They look to be dependant on provided variable document_root so I don't see any way why they should be global.

Answer (score 1):

It's not global variable. You've used a local variable w/o reaching its assignment, which was thought should have to be, by Python interpreter, just as the Exception said.

```
def foo():
    return x

def bar1(x):
    return x

def bar2(cond):
    if cond:
        x = x
    return x

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
            3 RETURN_VALUE 

>>> dis.dis(bar1)
2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
            3 RETURN_VALUE  

>>> dis.dis(bar2)       
2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (cond)
            3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15

3           6 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
            9 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
           12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)

4     >>   15 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
           18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Please note the difference between LOAD_GLOBAL in the output of foo and LOAD_FAST before RETURN_VALUE in bar1 and bar2, refs http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html

The issue usually means incomplete logic in code. For you code, better to unindent the last two line of code inside the last ELSE. This will fix the exception as well as underlining logic issue.